# Average grade in sql server manager studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to calculate students with average grades bigger than 8 .

```
select students FROM table1
GROUP BY students
HAVING AVG(grade)>8;
```

When i run the code it doesn't get anything in return , no error , nothing , just column students with no values. I checked table1 to see if there're enough values to calculate and the values are there.

What is wrong with that , can you help me ?

Comment: If you want the average, you need to include it in the `select`.

Comment: You should also post sample data to support your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the grade in your select statement. You can also provide a more accurate column name with `as`:

```
SELECT students, AVG(grade) as 'average'
FROM table1
GROUP BY Students
HAVING AVG(grade) > 8
```

Comment: Don't you want `AVG(grade)` in your select?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Yep, that's what I get for banging things out quickly before I'm fully awake in the morning. :P

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` includes the values you want to see, while the `HAVING` filters the results down.

```
SELECT students, AVG(grade) "Average Grade" FROM table1
GROUP BY students
HAVING AVG(grade)>8;
```